# Overload Bitwise NOT operator in Swift 2.1

Tags: swift

I've written a simple enum in swift similar to this:

```
enum Bit: UInt8 {
    case Zero = 0b0000_0000
    case One  = 0b0000_0001
}
```

Along with this, I've also written some bitwise operator overloads all of which work except for the NOT operator:

```
prefix func ~(bit: Bit) -> Bit {
    return Bit(rawValue: ~bit.rawValue)!
}
```

I've searched the Swift 2.1 documentation, and I don't see why this raises an exception.

*Just as a note, enum initializers are failable, hence the unwrapping. Also, I'm aware that there is already a `Bit` type in Swift (I've only given an example that is similar to my actual implementation).*

Comment: Note that Swift already has a [`enum Bit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Bit_Enumeration/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/s:OSs3Bit) type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the answer to my question was actually quite obvious, and I realized it while writing this post.

I did the following test in an Xcode Playground:

```
let zero = Bit.Zero
~zero.rawValue // 255 which is 0b1111_1111
```

So the issue is that `Bit` has no `case` that represents the binary value of `0b1111_1111`. Thus when the overloaded bitwise NOT function explicitly unwrapped the `Bit` optional, it was unwrapping `nil`.

```
// Not explicitly unwrapping the optional
Bit(rawValue: ~zero.rawValue) // nil

// Explicitly unwrapping the optional
Bit(rawValue: ~zero.rawValue)! // Exception ... EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION ...
```

The way I wanted it to work was the following:

```
prefix func ~(bit: Bit) -> Bit {
    switch bit {
    case .Zero:
        return .One
    case .One:
        return .Zero
    }
}
```

I hope this helps others with simple mistakes like mine.

Cheers!